# Error while redis package install

Tags: debian, ubuntu

On my server I use the Plesk control panel, I use the server from Hetzner Cloud. The problem is that when I try to install redis according to the instructions for the panel - https://ontwerps.nl/install-redis-with-plesk-onyx, in the end I get an error:

`This systems seems to use systemd.
Please take a look at the provided example service unit files in this directory, and adapt and install them. Sorry!`

And before that, i get the error `/bin/sh:1:pkg-config: not found` sometimes appears, but I correct it with the command `apt-get install -y pkg-config`, what could be the reason for the error? I tried to install on Debian 9 and on Ubuntu 18.04, the error is the same. How i can fix problem with systemd and install redis-stable?

Answer (score 2):

#### Steps I followed to make it run in my system

Comment out following lines in `redis-stable/utils/instal_server.sh` file

```
#bail if this system is managed by systemd
#_pid_1_exe="$(readlink -f /proc/1/exe)"
#if [ "${_pid_1_exe##*/}" = systemd ]
#then
#       echo "This systems seems to use systemd."
#       echo "Please take a look at the provided example service unit files in this directory, and adapt and install them. Sorry!"
#       exit 1
#fi
```

After this, you need to install `tcl tk`

> for ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install -y tcl tk`
>
> for RedHat: `sudo yum install tcl tk`

then inside `redis-stable/src`
run `sudo make install`

if it shows error like
`Hint: It's a good idea to run 'make test' ;)`

go back to redis-stable and run `make distclean` and again `sudo make install`

Finally, run the server by running `redis-server`

Atlast to check if Redis is working: `redis-cli ping`

Comment: Commenting on the specified code, worked for me as well. Thanks